# Python String Comparison with ==

Tags: python, string

Simple: `==` of strings is not working.

Using a typeform webhook, provides a json list of questions and answers to a user form. Question and answers are keyed on ID.

I know beforehand what questions and answer ID's are, I now want to loop over the answers.

For each Question ID, I loop through the answers to get the matching ID, and then I can pluck out the answer. Unfortunately, the equality operator is not working although the stings look the same?

Not pretty, but here is the code (only a small form):

```
for answer in user_answers:
    print("answer: " + answer['field']['id'])
    print("name id: " + form_fields["name"])
    print("bio id: " + form_fields["bio"])
    print("interests id: " + form_fields["interests"])  

    if answer == form_fields["name"]:
        print("A")
    elif answer == form_fields["bio"]:
        print("B")
    elif answer == form_fields["interests"]:
        print("C")
    else:
        print("D")
```

**Output**

```
answer: aoQDJzkrAVGA
name id: aoQDJzkrAVGA
bio id: aOsexSfYNQ8B
interests id: l6QZGmgHPXEQ
D
answer: aOsexSfYNQ8B
name id: aoQDJzkrAVGA
bio id: aOsexSfYNQ8B
interests id: l6QZGmgHPXEQ
D
answer: l6QZGmgHPXEQ
name id: aoQDJzkrAVGA
bio id: aOsexSfYNQ8B
interests id: l6QZGmgHPXEQ
D
```

We can see that the first pass answer and name ID match - should pring out A, but instead jumps out at the default clause and prints D.

Priority is to understand why this is not working, but also happy if a more efficient method is available to cope with longer forms?

Comment: Print the `repr()` of these strings to see *exactly* what's in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing `answer['field']['id']` but you're comparing the values to `answer`(which is the dictionary itself).  This will never return True because your dictionary is not equal to any of the strings.

You should do :

```
if answer['field']['id'] == form_fields["name"]:
   ...
```

For a more generalized code structure, you could do something like this:

```
ratings = [("name","A"),("bio","B"),("interests","C")]
result  = next((r for f,r in ratings if answer['field']['id']==form_fields[f]),"D")
```